# Angular 8 - Material Table not displaying correct data on delete

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material table that displays available options in the form of selects.

I have a root object which is the ngModel and serves to keep the options.

The options are retrieved from a database.

So lets say i have a root item of `menu`. This keep tracks of drinks and fruits in an array called `snacks` like so:

```
this.menu =
  {
    id: 1,
    snacks: [
      { fruitId: 1, drinkId: 1, deleted: false },
      { fruitId: 2, drinkId: 2, deleted: false },
      { fruitId: 3, drinkId: 2, deleted: false },
      { fruitId: 3, drinkId: 2, deleted: true },
    ]
  };
```

And then we define some fruits and drinks the user can choose:

```
this.fruits = [
  { id: 1, name: "Orange" },
  { id: 2, name: "Apple" },
  { id: 3, name: "Banana" },
  { id: 4, name: "Dragon fruit" }
];
this.drinks = [
  { id: 1, name: "Milk" },
  { id: 2, name: "Water" },
  { id: 3, name: "Juice" },
  { id: 4, name: "Soda" }
];
```

Then we map those in the table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="menuTableSource" #menuTable>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="fruit">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fruit </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let menuItem; let i = index;">
                                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="menu.snacks[i].fruitId" name="fruitId"
                                    #fruitId="ngModel">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit.id">
                                        {{ fruit.name }}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                        <ng-container matColumnDef="drink">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Drink </th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let menuItem; let i = index;">
                                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="menu.snacks[i].drinkId"
                                    name="drinkId" required>
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let drink of drinks" [value]="drink.id">
                                        {{drink.name}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </td>
                        </ng-container>

                    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="menuTableColumns"></tr>
                    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: menuTableColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Upon removing an item from this array and setting the table source data to this and calling `renderRows()` the table will drop the last entry ***even though the array of snacks is updated as expected***.

```
onRemoveMenuItem(menuItem: any): void {
const idx = this.menu.snacks.indexOf(menuItem);
if (idx >= 0) {
  this.menu.snacks[idx].deleted = true;
  this.menuTableSource.data = this.menu.snacks.filter(x => !x.deleted);
  this.menuTable.renderRows();
  }
}
```

Is this a bug or do I have to update the table in some other way?

Please see this stackblitz which demonstrates the isssue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzdjhj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
After looking to your code again. What I realized is that you are removing the right row and your data updates just fine but since you are displaying select dropdowns items from the `fruits` which creates confusion for you.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fruit">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fruit </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let menuItem; let i = index;">
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="menu.snacks[i].fruitId" name="fruitId"
#fruitId="ngModel">
<mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit.id">
  {{ fruit.name }}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

If you delete first item, the second item again shows orange in the select list because of this `<mat-option *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [value]="fruit.id">`.

**>>> Update Ends**

You can do this with passing the index of menu item and removing the item from the menu using the index passed.

Pass the index:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="remove">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> &nbsp; </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let menu; let i = index">
        <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="onRemoveMenuItem(i)">Remove</button>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

And your logic would be:

```
onRemoveMenuItem(i): void {
  this.menu.snacks.splice(i, 1);
  this.menuTableSource.data = this.menu.snacks;
  this.menuTable.renderRows();
}
```

You can later the property of the item if you do not want to remove it but just add property deleted for your other processes.

Comment: There's no way to filter out the deleted items (and keep them in the collection) while updating the data?

Comment: @HenrikM You are doing it absolutely right. You just need to review your data structures. The code is working as you expect.

Comment: "If you delete first item, the second item again shows orange in the select list because of this" - why does the select display that value since it's no longer part of the datasource data?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the issue again I realize I might be a bit of an idiot.

Maihan pointed me in the right direction.

Of course binding to the ngModel doesn't work because ngModel operates on the unfiltered collection.

But since I'd like to keep a reference to the deleted items I added a new array.

```
deletedSnacks = [];
```

And in my removeMenuItem function I push the snacks into that array, splice them and then upon submittning to the backend i simply concat them.

```
onRemoveMenuItem(menuItem: any): void {
const idx = this.menu.snacks.indexOf(menuItem);
if (idx >= 0) {
  this.menu.snacks[idx].deleted = true;
  this.deletedSnacks.push(this.menu.snacks[idx]);
  this.menu.snacks.splice(idx, 1);
  this.menuTableSource.data = this.menu.snacks;
  this.menuTable.renderRows();
  }
}
```